# Installing an internal Delock USB hub

Tags: usb, usb-hub, delock

I am installing an internal Delock 4-port USB 3.0 hub, so that I can have USB ports on the front panel of the machine.

I have plugged in the 4-pin cord, but I have a blue cord that has a USB contact on one end. I do not see any place to plug it in inside the box. Do I need it? If yes, does it go out the back and plug into one of those USB ports?

Comment: I tried to make your description clearer, but it's still a bit confusing. What's the "4-pin cord" for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing its [one of these](http://www.delock.com/produkte/F_246_intern_61833/merkmale/1.html) - 4 pin molex  (thats the fat white connector), for power, USB A (thats the [::::] shaped connector) plugs into a PC USB 3.0 port on the back of your computer on one side, and the A shaped USB B connector plugs into a connector at the back of the port.

[image]